# rails 3 making an API call when view is not open in browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, twitter, server, page-refresh

My app is making twitter API calls. I call the function in my view and added in beginning of the view (index.htnl.erb):

```
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60">  <!-- update every 1mn -->
</head>
```

So that the page is refreshed every minute and I can collect infos for my DB from the API call. I did not want to refresh all the views just this one (index.htnl.erb).
my app has just views: index.htnl.erb and tweet.html.erb.

How can I have my function called the API when the index page is not open in browser?
How to make it a server side call not client call?

Comment: put in common place where its accessible in all pages

Comment: I don't want it every where. I want to refresh this one view  (index.html.erb) on the server side whether the view is call or not.